# Create a handle that redirects to a channel?

Tags: slack

I would like to create a handle that, when pinged (e.g. "@hey-team"), sends a notification with a copy of the message to a private channel (e.g. #hey-team-notifs).

Is there a Slack feature or bot that will do this?